# RavenDB Error in IIS 7.5 / Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, iis, ravendb

I can't get RavenDB to run in my local copy of IIS and I can't seem to find any information about it. I have the proper permissions set up on the folder and files and adjusted the Application pool as the set-up instructions stated but still it doesn't seem to work. The only (unhelpful) error I get is this:

```
Could not authenticate against the server


Message: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.10411.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer
Uri: /databases?database=Default
Server Uri: http://localhost:82/docs/Raven/Databases/Kiosk

-- Error Information --
System.Net.WebException: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.10411.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise)

Inner StackTrace: 
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent)
   at Raven.Studio.Commands.CreateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Execute>b__0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicate that you didn't install/enabled Windows Auth in IIS

Comment: Windows Authentication is not available on Windows 7 Home Premium... can you disable the RavenDB authentication (development machine)?